# Reload Time in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

So I noticed a long time ago in ***World of Tanks*** when I look at any *gun* specifications, for **Aiming time** It gives me a value (Lets say 2.7), and then once I go in battle, the reload time says 5.1 **(Near the aiming circle)**!

My point is, there is no indication while looking at gun specifications where the *real* Aiming time **(Time in (s) to reload a shell)**  like the once displayed in battle. This is really bad sinse I dont know how much time it takes for that gun to reload!

Where is located (What piece of text) the time to **reload a shell** in ***World of Tanks***?

Comment: Aiming time and reload time are two separate numbers, yet you seem to be using them interchangeably.  The reload time is the time it takes from when you fire to when the next shell is loaded.  Aiming time is how long it takes for the aiming circle to fully shrink after moving or firing (though the actual time it takes is affected by a number of hidden stats on each tank).  Both numbers are displayed under the "Firepower" section when you select a tank in your garage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing reload and aiming time, they are not the same thing.

The reload time of the gun is the time it takes to load a shell in the gun. After reloading you can fire. The reload time for a tank is visible in the firepower section in your garage (see red arrow in the screenshot below).

Aiming time is the time for the tank to fully aim so it will fire with it's maximum accuracy. It is possible to fire the gun before you fully aim, but it is less likely you will hit your intended target. See the blue arrow below for where to find aiming time.

[image: Aim vs reload in world of tanks]

Please note that you will need to re-aim after moving the tank, or rotating the turret as the aiming timer will be (partially) reset when doing that.

Comment: Oh wow. They changed it. It was confusing before the new update, but now its easier to know.

Comment: Isn't the aiming time the time to reduce the size of the aiming reticle by a 1/3 and _not_ the time to _fully_ aim?

Comment: @DrP3pp3r *Aiming time* is the time necessary to reduce reticle by 60%, not 1/3 nor fully aim (in this screenshot, the fully aiming time would be a little more than 4 seconds)